# Error while trying to display multiple google charts on a single page

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I have already looked into the various questions posted on this site regarding this. However, my problem is slightly different. I have the following javascript code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["corechart", "bar"]});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() 
            {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Dept.', 'Actual strength'],
                    ['Computer Sc. & Engineering', 20],
                    ['Mechanical Engineering',     15],
                    ['Electrical Engineering',     13],
                    ['Humanities & Social Sc',     15]
                ]);

                var options1 = {
                    'title': 'Department wise distribution of faculties',
                    'is3D': true
                };
                var chart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById("instStat1_1"));
                chart1.draw(data, options1);

                var options2 = {
                    chart: {
                        title: 'Sanctioned vs Actual Department Analysis'
                    }
                };
                var chart2 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById("instStat1_2"));
                chart2.draw(data, options2);



                var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                  ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
                  ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
                  ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
                  ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
                  ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
                ]);

                var options = {
                    chart: {
                  title: 'Company Performance',
                    subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
                }
                };

                var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('deptStat3'));

                chart.draw(data1, options);
            }
        </script>
```

The problem is that the first two charts are getting displayed. HOwever, there is small red-colored "error" message in the div corresponding to the third chart. The third chart when ran on an individual web page, displays properly (it is actually the same chart as [displayed here on official google site](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Material)). The following is my div element:

```
<div class="well">
    <div id="deptStat3" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
</div>
```

Can anybody please help me in finding out the mistake?

**UPDATE**
The same graph when rendered in Chrome is rendered partially instead of not being rendered at all, although way too smaller than the mentioned height. I am using "Material Column Charts" for the 3rd graph by the way.

Comment: Hard to say, what does the error message says? Your code works under the assumption that all 3 divs are present in the DOM.

Comment: @davidkonrad Hello, my code does contain all the 3 divs. But I am unable to see any error message. There is only a small red colored rectangle near the div which contains the word "error" with no other description. Moreover, the same graph when redered in Chrome is rendered partially instead of not being rendered at all... I am using "Material column charts" for the 3rd graph btw.

Comment: It should work right away - is does here -> http://jsfiddle.net/Lrvtr935/

Comment: @davidkonrad Well, it worked even on my browser when I coded the 3rd graph separately in an another HTML file... I still dont know what the issue is..